# Cosine similarity and SVC using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to utilize the cosine similarity kernel to text classification with SVM with a raw dataset of 1000 words:

```
# Libraries
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(raw_data[:, 0], raw_data[:, 1], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# CountVectorizer
c = CountVectorizer(max_features=1000, analyzer = "char")
X_train = c.fit_transform(x_train).toarray()
X_test = c.transform(x_test).toarray()

# Kernel
cosine_X_tr = cosine_similarity(X_train)
cosine_X_tst = cosine_similarity(X_test)

# SVM
svm_model = SVC(kernel="precomputed")
svm_model.fit(cosine_X_tr, y_train)
y_pred = svm_model.predict(cosine_X_tst)
```

But that code throws the following error:

```
ValueError: X has 330 features, but SVC is expecting 670 features as input
```

I've tried the following, but I don't know it is mathematically accurate and because also I want to implement other custom kernels not implemented within `scikit-learn` like histogram intersection:

```
cosine_X_tst = cosine_similarity(X_test, X_train)
```

So, basically the main problem resides in the dimensions of the matrix SVC recieves. Once `CountVectorizer` is applied to train and test datasets those have `1000 features` because of `max_features` parameter:

- Train dataset of shape `(670, 1000)`
- Test dataset of shape `(330, 1000)`

But after applying cosine similarity are converted to squared matrices:

- Train dataset of shape `(670, 670)`
- Test dataset of shape `(330, 330)`

When `SVC` is fitted to train data it learns `670 features` and will not be able to predict test dataset because has a different number of features (`330`). So, how can i solve that problem and be able to use custom kernels with `SVC`?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how can i solve that problem and be able to use custom kernels with `SVC`?

Define a function yourself, and pass that function to the `kernel` parmeter in `SVC()`, like: `SVC(kernel=your_custom_function)`. See [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html).

---

Also, you should use the `cosine_similarity` kernel like below in your code:

```
svm_model = SVC(kernel=cosine_similarity)
svm_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svm_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: But that will not solve the problem with the shape of the dataset. I mean, I don't know if its mathematically correct to calculate the kernel `K(x, y)` being `x = x_test` and `y = x_train` for the test dataset.

Comment: @ukmz75 When you call `cosine_similarity(X)`, it just calculates the pair-wise cosine similarity between each row in `X` - that's why you got a symmetric matrix of the shape (n_samples, n_samples) out of it. You could technically "solve" your issue by making the number of samples in your `X_train` and `X_test` equal, but that would not make sense.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I've seen a solution where `cosine_similarity(X_test, X_train)` for the test dataset, but I'm not sure of that. And if I implement the kernel from scratch the dimension problem will persist, I guess